# Create controller to back model with underscore in the name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model `higher_ed.rb` that is a subclass of `group.rb`. I'd like to back up `higher_ed.rb` with a Controller. The fact that there are specifics as to plural in the controller and singular in the model confuses a beginner like me enough. Throwing the underscore adds to that, so any help would be appreciated.

I did take a crack at it but got an error of `uninitialized constant HigheredsController`. That makes sense because my controller is camel cased as `HigherEdsController`. What am I doing wrong?

Inside of my file is the following:

```
class HigherEd < Group
end
```

I tried to run the following to create the appropriate controller:

```
rails g controller higher_eds
```

I then put the following in my `routes.rb`:

```
resources :highereds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes file should be:

```
resources :higher_eds
```